# How to detect enteties in binary messages?

Tags: detection

Say we have 100000 protobuf formated messages and 100000 bson messages or any other non compressing binary formater. They are in one stack, not compressed. Behind bouth encoding types are lying data structures. Is it possible to detect/clusterize messages from same data structures not having original protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Professing no specific knowledge on either, but taking a cursory look at bson, I would say yes.

The bson format is kind enough to at least provide a predictable pattern, as detailed on [the bson wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON).

```
Bson:
\x16\x00\x00\x00                   // total document size
\x02                               // 0x02 = type String
hello\x00                          // field name
\x06\x00\x00\x00world\x00          // field value
\x00                               // 0x00 = type EOO ('end of object')
```

According to [Google's documentation for protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding?hl=en), the messages should generally be much smaller as the format was designed to be much more terse and operate over the wire.

So if you're finding messages with a size header and end of object byte, you've likely got a bson message.

Comment: main question is that I have messages as separated files and I want to find any meaning in them.

Comment: I think in the case of bson, yes, the structure is well documented.  It might be more difficult with protbuf unless you know what the protocol is, but figuring out which one you have should be no trouble, which means you can derive meaning reliably from some of them.  Whether there is a context for the information is another, perhaps more important consideration.